# Python: Loop to check if an input is valid or not line by line

Tags: python, loops

Given the following inputs that simulate a grid with the respective dimensions:

```py
totLines = int(input("Indicate the number os lines: "))
totColunms = int(input("Indicate the number of columns: "))
```

I want to check whether the input is valid or not (every digit must be between 0 and 20). The code should check each line of the grid and tell the user if the input is valid and if not ask for another input. The problem is that my code only checks the first digit of line1, the second digit of the line2, and so on. For instance, in a 3x3 grid, if I input the following numbers for line1 (separated by spaces) -  21 10 10 - the code is gonna tell me that the input is not valid, but if I put the incorrect digit in position 2 - 10 21 10 - the code is not gonna find any problem. I know the problem must be related to how I´m doing the loop but I can´t understand how to solve this. This is something easy to do but It´s my first time learning a programming language and I still have a lot to learn. Thanks!

```py
for lin in range (1, totLines+1):
    print("Line", str(lin))
    while True:
        sMoves = input("Movement for this line: ")
        listMoves = sMoves.split()
        listMovesINT = list(map(int, listMoves))
        if listMovesINT[lin-1] > 0 and listMovesINT[lin-1] <= 20:
            break
        else:
            print ("Not a valid integer")
            continue
```

Comment: Maybe you need a double loop: for each line, for each column, check.

Comment: Because you should loop on ```listMovesINT``` which is a list, and you are checking only the digit at line ```lin-1```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest putting the logic to get a valid list of moves in its own function, using `all()` to test all the values in the list (you don't need the current value of `lin` or anything else in the main loop to figure this out, and putting this task in its own function makes it easier to focus on it without accidentally mixing in other parts of your program):

```
def get_movement() -> list[int]:
    """Get a list of movement values between 1 and 20."""
    while True:
        try:
            moves = [int(n) for n in input("Movement for this line:").split()]
            if not all(1 <= n <= 20 for n in moves):
                raise ValueError("all values must be between 1 and 20")
            return moves
        except ValueError as e:
            print("Not a valid integer:", e)
```

and then in your main loop you can do:

```
for lin in range (1, totLines+1):
    print("Line", lin)
    moves = get_movement()
    # do whatever thing with moves
```

Comment: I greatly appreciate it! That´s exactly what I wanted to do. However, I still have a problem since I want to use the inputted numbers to check additional things. I can't put the input inside the function because I want to make other functions to see if the input satisfies other criteria. In order to avoid this, I've been attempting to modify the function to receive an input from "outside" but I'm not sure how should I proceed. Sorry in advance if I said something "dumb"!

Comment: You could have `get_movement` take a list of validator functions to test the input against.  If this is your first time learning a programming language, though, you might have taken on an excessively complex starter project...

Answer (score 0):

As you noticed, you are "binding" the items in your input to your "*board*" (sort of the "*board*"... the `totLines` variable).

But you really just want to verify one input at a time, right? When the user writes the set of movements for any given line, it doesn't really matter whether it's for the first line of the "board" or for the last. Maybe you want the line index to display a nice prompt message, but that's about it. When it comes to ensuring that the input is valid, you really don't need the line for anything, isn't it?

So it all boils down to verifying that the inputs for any given line are valid, and keep pestering the user until they (all) are. Something like:

```
    valid_input = False
    while not valid_input:
        sMoves = input("Movement for this line: ")
        listMoves = sMoves.split()
        listMovesINT = list(map(int, listMoves))
        valid_input = all((0 < move <= 20) for move in listMovesINT)
        if not valid_input:
            print("One of the movements is not valid")
```

If you wanna use the number of total lines (`totLines`) to show a little bit more human-friendly prompt and then make the code a bit more like what you have it (with a `for` loop), you can just wrap the `while not valid_input` like this:

```
    totLines = int(input("Indicate the number os lines: "))
    for lineNum in range(1, totLines + 1):
        valid_input = False
        while not valid_input:
            sMoves = input(f"Movement for line {lineNum}: ")
            listMoves = sMoves.split()
            listMovesINT = list(map(int, listMoves))
            valid_input = all((0 < move <= 20) for move in listMovesINT)
            if not valid_input:
                print("One of the movements is not valid")
```

Answer (score 0):

First, your code only check one integer per line.
You have an index but it is a line index (lin-1), not a number index.
Was the "while True" supposed to iterate over numbers. If yes, it should be after the "split()".

Here's a working example:

```
matrix = []
totlines=3
for i in range( totlines):
  line = input( "... ")
  numbers = [ int( text) for text in line.split()] # convert list of asciiNumbers to list of 3 integers
  for number in numbers:
    if (number <= 0) or (number>20):
      print( "Invalid number in line", i, ":", numbers)
  matrix.append( numbers)

print( matrix)
```